# Doing jframe.setType(Window.Type.POPUP) in Java 1.6

Tags: java, popup, window, java-6

I need to do something to the effect of

```
jframe.setType(Window.Type.POPUP);
```

but in Java 1.6. (The [`setType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setType(java.awt.Window.Type)) method was introduced in Java 1.7.)

Can't upgrade to 1.7 at the moment because reasons.

Comment: Then you can't use the functionality, because of "reasons" - You could use a `JWindow` or remove the window decorations, which might  produce a simular result

Comment: I know I can't use `setType` because of reasons, but was there no support for creating such popups in Java 1.6? Specifically, I'm using a tiling window manager and `JWindow` doesn't set the floating WM hint by default, so my popup gets tiled along side other windows. With the `setType(Window.Type.POPUP)` everything works properly, and the window shows up floating in my window manager. (I'm happy to change from JFrame if that helps me.) I've successfully got rid of window decorations etc already.

Comment: _"because reasons"_ - Can I ask what reasons? You made me curious.

Comment: Then you're stuck - because you don't have the ability to change the way that the native window is created

Comment: @MadProgrammer Should I interpret that as there was no way to achieve this type of floating windows in the Java 1.6 days?

Comment: AFAIK - You can't change the way that the native frame is created (and I don't know anyway to connect a natively built window into the Swing Event Queue), that would suggest that, no, you don't have any options available to you.  You might consider having a look at the JNI/JNA APIs to see if there is someway to create a native window of your own and connect it to the Swing pipeline, but I'm not aware of any

Comment: Hmm.. Seems to be working with `JDialog`. Since both `JDialog` and `JFrame` are `Window`s, I wonder if whatever `JDialog` does can also be done with a `Window`. Otherwise I'll just try switching to `JDialog`.